Sum values in child edges of igraph/tidygraph
I have a sf_network object where I would like to sum all values from each edge such that the root edge would be equal to the sum of all the others. I've made a simple example for testing purposes below. I am working with igraph and tidygraph and would prefer a solution that uses them.
#Testing Data    
tree_t<-create_tree(20, 3) |>
  mutate(leaf = node_is_leaf())
    
iris_tree <- tree_t %>% 
  morph(to_linegraph) %>%  #Morphing to convert edges to nodes
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  mutate(value_2_sum = 1) |>
  mutate(summed_value = map_bfs_back_dbl(node_is_root(), .f = function(node, path, ...) {
    nodes <- .N()
    if (is.null(nodes$leaf[node])) return(sum(nodes[path$node,]$value_2_sum,nodes$value_2_sum[node],na.rm = T)) 
    return(sum(path$result[[1]],nodes$value_2_sum[node],na.rm=T)) #Problem with the logic here I think.
  })) |>
  unmorph()

#Plot
ggraph(iris_tree) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal2(aes(colour = summed_value, label = summed_value)) + 
  theme_graph()

It should be obvious but as you can see in the plot although most edges have their values correctly added but the first 4 on the top left of the chart is not catching the values from below. It seems to be an issue with the second return call. The path$results call I think is the issue but I am not sure. Any thoughts are welcome.

I got lucky and found an example in the map_dfs_back help file which led me to this solution. It may look funny how the values are adding up but you have to remember that every edge adds an additional value, so you are adding all the values from the child edges plus a value for the current edge. In this case all values are 1 for simplicity. Hopefully this helps someone else in the future trying to do something similar.
library(tidygraph)
#> Warning: package 'tidygraph' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'tidygraph'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(ggraph)
#> Warning: package 'ggraph' was built under R version 4.3.3
#> Loading required package: ggplot2

#Same example data
tree_t<-create_tree(20, 3)
  
iris_tree <- tree_t %>%
  morph(to_linegraph) %>%
  activate(nodes) %>% 
  mutate(value_2_sum = 1,leaf = node_is_leaf()) |>
  mutate(summed_value = map_bfs_back(node_is_root(), .f = function(node, path, dist, ...) {
    if (nrow(path) == 0) .N()$value_2_sum[node]
    else {
      sum(.N()$value_2_sum[node],unlist(path$result[path$dist - dist <= 2]),na.rm=T) #Some magic inspired by the map_dfs_back help file.
    }
  })) |>
  unmorph()


ggraph(iris_tree) + 
  geom_edge_diagonal2(aes(colour = summed_value, label = summed_value)) + 
  theme_graph()
#> Using "tree" as default layout


Created on 2024-05-13 with reprex v2.1.0
